# Why are duplicate ID's an error in HTML5 checkup?

Tags: css, html

I have the following code in HTML:

```
<span>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="caption">
            <p id="first">Text1</p>
            <p id="desc">click to read</p>
        </span>
        <img class="img_link" src="img/thing1.jpg" width="218" height="181" 
             alt="thing1"/>
    </a>
</span>
<span>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="caption">
            <p id="first">Text2</p>
            <p id="desc">click to read</p>
        </span>
        <img class="img_link" src="img/thing2.jpg" width="218" height="181" 
             alt="thing2"/>
    </a>
</span>
```

This code is used for making an overlayed text transition for images in CSS, but if I want to validate this HTML code, it says I have a duplicate ID (here "first" and "desc") but I honestly wouldn't know how I can simplify this. I need to resize "first" with font-size, and "desc" too.

For example: the paragraph with id "first" has to be 14px, and the paragraph with "desc" has to be 12px.

Only those <"p"> (without the quote) elements can not be a child element in the "span" element.

I wouldn't know how to solve this, do you guys have a solution?

Thanks for the answers, I've already changed the ID's to a class.

Still, I wouldn't know how to resize class "first" and "desc" in two different font sizes, because it's apparently "not done" to put a block element in an inline element

EDIT 3: Solved! Using div's is the best solution, I'm using this for school (kind of a project) for making a gallery. With float: left; I can place those images next to eachother.

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Use a class, IDs are by definition unique. `<p class="first">...</p>` Select it in CSS by `p.first { ... }`

Comment: People still 'validate' HTML? How very 1995 and irrelevant.

Comment: What is the question? The title asks a pointless question (duplicate `id` values are invalid because `id` attributes are defined to be unique), and the body does not really ask any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made several mistakes:

- id attribute is of type #ID which by the HTML/SGML standard is defined to be unique, if you want to show duplicates you should use class  attribute (this is part of why there's getElement***s***ByClassName returning a list but getElementById returning only a single item in the JavaScript DOM API)
- span is inline element, while p is a block element, HTML does not allow block element inside inline element. You should replace your span with div. You can use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` if you want it to appear like inline level elements. Example of inline elements include: a, span, etc; example of block elements include: div, p, ul, li, etc.

Comment: Wow thanks, using a <div> is much better. It works and the errors are gone. Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to:

```
<p class="first">
```

and

```
<p class="desc">
```

EDIT:
You best remove the `spans` completely. You don't need them. If you feel you need them to wrap block-level elements, you can do that with `divs`

Comment: Yes, thank you! Changing it to class will remove the dubplicate ID error, but the <p> element in the <span> element error still shows.

Comment: you cannot put another tags into a span tag except `i, b, strong ...`

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the element type.

```
<p> tag is block level element 

<span> tag is a inline element
```

Therefore encapsulating a **block** level element inside an **inline** level element is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I resize 2 different sentences in a <span> then?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can use **classes**.
Change:

1.

```
id="first" -- into --> class="first"
id="desc" -- into --> class="desc"
```

2.
You cannot put another tags into a `span` tag **except** `<i>, <b>, <strong>, and <br /> ...`
With `<br/ >` you can have 2 lines in your `span` tag

Comment: Of the 113 HTML5 conforming elements in the HTML namespace, no fewer than 53 can validly appear inside a span element. Which is a lot more than the 4 you list.